# Resetting GTK Settings: Ambiance Menu Colors

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, themes, gtk

Whenever I use either Ambiance, or a theme that is based off of Ambiance (Ambiance-Colors for example), the menu text for the unity menus as well as all drop down menus is dark, like so:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/l7uaGmw.png].

The unavailable menu items, i.e. the grayed out entries, are their normal color. I have attempted to do the following. Note I am on 14.04:

- Reinstall `light-themes` package, and `gtk3.0` package
- `dconf reset -f /org/compiz`
- Remove `.gtk-2.0` , `3.0`, `.gnome2`, `.gnome` folders, as well as similar folders in `.config`

Comment: Have you tried logging using other user account?

Comment: I made a fresh account and logged in. The bug persists not only in the other user account, but also in the lightdm login screen.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtk-3-common light-themes gtk3.0
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
sudo reboot
```

And it was OK for me!

it is all those things, described in previous 2 posts!

Answer (score 1):

After force reinstalling `libgtk-3-common` and restarting my machine, the issue has been fixed. Seems as if I removed a file that belonged to this package, or otherwise modified it.

Comment: I tried it too, but it didn't help me...